# subclipse execute task on checkout

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have a SVN repo for a Javascript web frontend.

After `checkout` I need to modify some file for fit the project to development environment.

I'm doing that by hand every time but it would be handy if the operation can be automated by Eclipse.

Is it possible with Subclipse/Ecplise to execute a task after SVN `checkout` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would need to write an Eclipse plugin.  You could then hook into the event and run your code.  There are probably a lot of ways to do this, but the one that springs to mind would be to create a "Builder".  You would then associate this Builder with your project and it would be stored in the .project file so that it is added automatically when the project is checked out.  Just as Builders know to compile your .java code after the projects is checked out, your builder would do the things you wanted to have happen.